# Change position of image for 3.5 and 4 inch screens

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an iPhone app that I'm optimising for the iPhone 5's 4-inch screen. I also want it to work with iOS 6. I turned off autolayout to get it to work with iOS 6. I want everything in the view to stay the same distance from the bottom of the screen for both screen sizes. How do i do this?

Comment: iOS 6 supports autolayout, so why don't you use it ?

Comment: Okay, turned it back on and seems to work okay, how can I set everything to stay same distance from bottom?

Comment: @user2397282 Using autolayout and "distance from bottom" constraint?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Xcode and iPhone programming, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Comment: Thanks CaptJak! Exactly what I wanted!!